# In Oracle I want to create a "routing interface" which insert into separate tables based on parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, partitioning

I need to find a solution to the following problem: there should be a common and single "interface" that I can use in an insert into statement, something like this: `insert into INTERFACE (fields) select ...`
But there are many tables with the same structure behind the interface which should decide based on list of values (coming in a field) where to put the data. The tables are partitioned by range interval (daily) right now.

I was thinking about having a composite partitioned table which cannot be SELECT-ed to avoid mixing different type of data in a single select query, but creating views on the top of it. In this case the table should be partitioned like this: partition by list FIELD subpartition by range interval. But oracle 12 does not support this.

Any idea how to solve this? (There is a reason why I need a single interface and why I have to store data separately.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your first paragraph, it sounds like you just want `interface` to be a view with an `instead of insert` trigger that puts data in whatever physical tables you want.  Though it would seem more reasonable to have a stored procedure that your application calls rather than doing an `insert` and let that proc determine where to put the data.  But then your second paragraph confuses me because I don't see how that addresses the problem you outline in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Justin! The problem: we desiged a playground for marketing campaign with some code-review. Junior colleagues creates an SQL that is stored in a table and executed by a daily job with some param replacement (i.e. date to run against)
So I have to separate somehow the playground data from the production one, but still using the same insert  query with a STATUS field in the code table. If the status is PROD then the result should go into RESULT_PROD table, otherwise into a RESULT_OTHER table. Not a nice solution (terrible I know, but that's what we have right now).

Comment: The BAU process is that they create sqls with bunch of DROP TABLE, CREATE table statement and manually replaces the filtering criteria. But some of them is very regular and must be executed on daily/weekly/monthly bases by only replacing the daterange. We have no permanent IT solution, so just be able to use our common schemas or our private one with role based authorisation.

Designing an application is not an option because our management does not give money for such development, and our dwh development is too slow for the changes occures in our BAU operation.

Comment: I'm not sure what BAU stands for here?  Business <<something>> Unit?  But I don't see a business unit creating SQL statements.  If you're trying to cook up some sort of hack to work around a poorly designed existing process, I'd tend to my initial suggestion of a view with a trigger on it.  That's certainly sufficient to handle conditionally sending an insert to one table or another.  I don't understand what you want to do with DDL statements.

Comment: Sorry! BAU means business as usual, so the normal daily workload. 
Sounds good, let me to try that. Believe me, I would make it a more professional way but my hands are tied. That's why I am feeling a pain due to this workaround/hack I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT ALL` syntax can help easily route data to specific tables based on conditions:

```
create table interface1(a number, b number);
create table interface2(a number, b number);

insert all
    when a <= 1 then
        into interface1
    else
        into interface2
select '1' a, 2 b from dual;
```

Comment: Oh, man! LOL! It is soooo simple :) Like it very much! Thank you! Never saw this solution yet. You saved me tons of headache! Thank you!